# How do I move .MinimumLevel.Override to appsettings.json?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

Is there a way to move the `MinimumLevel` overrides to appsettings.json?

Sometimes I don't want to display the system logs, so I do

```
.MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
```

and sometimes I want to keep an eye on the requests for debugging purposes:

```
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting", LogEventLevel.Debug)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware", LogEventLevel.Debug)
```

So is there a better way to do that in appsettings.json?

```cs
public static class LoggingExtensions
{
    public static IHostBuilder AddLogging(this IHostBuilder builder, LogEventLevel minLevelLocal = LogEventLevel.Information)
    {
        const string outputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Is(minLevelLocal)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
            // .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting", LogEventLevel.Debug)
            // .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware", LogEventLevel.Debug)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithMachineName()
            .Enrich.WithProcessName()
            .Enrich.WithMemoryUsage()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate)
            .CreateLogger();

        return builder.UseSerilog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#minimumlevel-levelswitches-overrides-and-dynamic-reload) library has explicit support for this.

```json
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

And to tell it to read the config from there:

```cs
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an IConfiguration to your extension and extract the value that way.

```cs
public static void AddLogging(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var minLevelString = configuration.GetValue<string>("Logger:MinLevel");
    var minLevel = Enum.Parse<LogEventLevel>(minLevelString);
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Is(minLevel).CreateLogger();
}
```